# Accessing the current overlay number in beamer

Tags: beamer, counters, overlays

For some `beamer` related code in one of my packages, I need to access the current overlay number. I mean the internal number used for things like `\only<1>{..}`.

```
\only<1>{ Some internal number must be one in here }
\only<2>{ But 2 in here }
\only<1-5>{\includegraphics[page=(current overlay number)]{...}}
```

I checked the `beamer` manual and did not find any information about this. I checked the source code and found some related macros/counters, but they didn't always hold the correct values. `\beamerpauses` seems not the correct one either. Does anyone know the "official" counter/macro for this number?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may be looking for the internal counter

```
\beamer@slideinframe
```

as defined in [`beamerbasedecode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasedecode.sty): It is the value `beamer` consults when encountering something like `\only<1,3-5>{...}` to check whether to display or to hide the content.

A small demonstration on how to access this value:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<1>{ Some internal number must be \overlaynumber\ in here }
\only<2>{ But \overlaynumber\ in here }

\only<1-5>{Graphic \overlaynumber}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems indeed the right counter. How exactly did you find it?

Comment: @MartinScharrer I already had fun with the decode routine when answering previous questions, so I knew where to look ;-)

Comment: This gives wrong answer for some reason. It counts wrong. For a frame with two slides, `\overlaynumber\` is 2 on both pages.