# Cropping standalone documents using the beamer option

Tags: beamer, standalone, crop

I have a beamer presentation in which a figure takes a bit long to compile. And I do not want to use externalize. Figures in non-beamer documents can be conveniently produced with standalone. However, if one uses the beamer option there, as is explained in the manual, the figure won't get cropped. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,yscale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,width=8cm,height=4cm,clip=false] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{ 
            color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(pow(x,2)/15)};
\end{axis}
\node at (-0.2,1) {observer};
\node at (7,1) {source};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to persuade standalone to crop the document, or is there an alternative that allows one to achieve this.

**NOTE**: I was told by samcarter that one could achieve this by changing the font. I agree that this would allow me solve the issue in the present example, but I'd would like to have a general solution. (And no externalize.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `beamer` option normally also sets `preview=false,crop=false,varwidth=false`. The `crop=false` key can be reverted by passing it as an additional argument:

```
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,yscale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,width=8cm,height=4cm,clip=false] 
\addplot[domain=20:300,samples=800,        
colormap={}{ 
            color(2cm)=(red);
            color(16cm)=(blue);
        },
        ultra thick, point meta=x*x,mesh]{sin(pow(x,2)/15)};
\end{axis}
\node at (-0.4,0) {observer};
\node at (7,1) {source};

\draw (-0.4,0.5) pic [scale=0.4,duck/glasses] {duck};

\begin{scope}[yscale=-0.6,xscale=-0.3,yshift=-100,xshift=40]
\fill[gray] (-2.9466,-0.3003) -- (-3.1837,0.4402) -- (-2.7744,0.5708) -- (-2.7308,0.4348) -- (-1.8176,0.7262) -- (-2.6937,2.5325) -- (-2.4891,2.6173) -- (-1.7766,1.1484) -- (-1.7910,2.8438) -- (-1.5698,2.8326) -- (-1.5560,1.2208) -- (-0.8785,2.6173) -- (-0.6739,2.5325) -- (-1.5011,0.8272) -- (-0.3532,1.1935) -- (-0.3096,1.0574) -- (-0.1147,1.1196) -- (-0.0566,0.9382) -- (-0.2516,0.8760) -- (-0.2032,0.7249) -- (-2.5809,-0.0337) -- (-2.5373,-0.1697) -- (-2.9466,-0.3003) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sooo simple ;-)

Comment: samcarter, @marmot: Indeed. Also the `=true` is optional. Cropping is disabled with `beamer` option by default.

Comment: @marmot [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168705/1952) is a possible application of `crop=false` by default with `beamer`

Comment: @marmot Added the missing observer :)

Comment: @samcarter Oh, so cute!!!! BTW, yet another [message that got swallowed](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/do-you-also-fail-to-get-some-messages), I just saw this by accident....

Comment: @marmot Maybe there is a filter for duck related messages :)

Comment: @samcarter This must be a very intelligent filter as there was no duck in your message... And your last one had a duck in and did not get swallowed, so maybe one has to add ducks to make sure that he message gets delivered?

Comment: @marmot Only messages with "duck" will produce a notification :)