# What is the best way to combine tikz pictures and beamer overlays

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

I am currently working on a conference presentation and I am using the very nice `tikz` and `pgfplots`packages in combination with `beamer`.

To stress out some content in my figures, I use `beamer`'s overlay system.

When I use some small `tikzpicture`s everything is integrated inside the document using some `\input` commands. However, for large `pgfplots` figures (you see me coming), I have quite long compilation times.

My current solution is to precompile my big pictures separately using multiple `tikzpicture`s and to call some `\includegraphics` with overlay options.

Beamer code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics<1>[page=1]{image}
\includegraphics<2>[page=2]{image}
\includegraphics<3->[page=3]{image}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

where `image` is built using

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
    % Plot to be displayed on overlay 1
        \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=100]{x}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        % Plots to be displayed on overlay 2
        \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=100]{x}; 
        \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=100]{x^2}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% And so on
\end{document}
```

I know there are some externalization ways to do this, but I was wondering what the opinion of the community was on this matter.

Sorry in advance, if this is a double.

**EDIT related to `standalone` `beamer` option**

Using `standalone` with the `beamer` option seems to produce an nteresting result (thanks samcarter). However, the output has the size of a `beamer` frame, instead of fitting the pgfplots axis. See the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\only<1>{\addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x};}
\addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x^2};
\addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x^3};
\only<4>{\addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x^4}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to answer if you include some example.

Comment: You could also use the standalone class to pre-compile the figures including overlays - the class has a special beamer option to allow for overlays and such.

Comment: Yes, it does. This option will allow overlays. As a side effect, it will also set the papersize to the one from beamer and not crop the images, but this can easily be undone.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment. It is working nicely, except for the paper size. Do you have any ideas to redefine the paper size to fit the actual pictures ?

Comment: Just found an old answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426910/cropping-standalone-documents-using-the-beamer-option/426912#426912

Comment: Oh, I just realized that `\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}` does not work for your MWE. I'll investigate

Comment: @samcarter, a quick and dumb question. How do you include the ouput pdf inside the main document to keep overlay definitions ?

Comment: You mean instead of your current `\includegraphics<1>[page=1]{image}
\includegraphics<2>[page=2]{image}
\includegraphics<3->[page=3]{image}`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: If there are multiple overlays a loop could be used to simplify this. Or `\multiinclude` could be helpful, but this would probably require splitting `image.pdf` into multiple file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the `tikz` and `preview` options to `standalone`:

```
\documentclass[beamer,tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[]
  \only<1>{\addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x};}
  \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x^2};
  \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x^3};
  \only<4>{\addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100]{x^4}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `pdflatex` results in a nicely cropped, 4 page PDF. For easy embedding into the `beamer` frames, I recommend the following pattern:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \foreach \ov/\pg in {1/1,2/2,3-/3}{ 
    \includegraphics<\ov>[page=\pg]{image.pdf}
  } 
  \onslide<4>{Still the last figure!}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```