# How to change the page width to infinite for beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

My purpose to use `beamer` class is not to make a presentation, instead I just want to make gifs. Like using `standalone` for make pngs.

However, when `beamer` is used, seems the page width is fixed. If I draw too many things, the element may go out of the paper. Using the following example, element `D` comes out of visible area

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, matrix, chains, scopes, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{myrect/.style n args = {4}{font=\footnotesize \ttfamily, align=left, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum width=#1cm, minimum height=#2cm, fill=#3, draw=#4}}
    \tikzset{myrect/.default={3}{1}{white}{black}}
    \tikzset{mycon/.style = {rounded corners}}
    \begin{frame}[t,fragile]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix (layer1) [matrix of nodes, nodes={myrect}, column sep=1cm] {
                A&
                |[visible on=<2->]| B&
                |[visible on=<3->]| C&
                |[visible on=<4->]| D\\
            };
            {
                [start chain,every on chain/.style={join}, every join/.style={->}]
                \chainin (layer1-1-1) [];
                \only<5->{\chainin (layer1-1-2) [];}
                \only<6->{\chainin (layer1-1-3) [];}
                \only<7->{\chainin (layer1-1-4) [];}
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried the `shrink` option for frame, it can take some effect, but not quite adaptive, have to specify the resize percentage manually. Is there ways to make beamer page width infinite so that I don't need to worry about the draw area?

Comment: Have a look at [this nice solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435559/141947) by @Daniel to combine `standalone` and `overlays`

Comment: What is the conceptual difference between producing PNGs and GIF?

Comment: @AlexG, I want to generate animations using gif. So I use `beamer` instead of `standalone`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer use the `geometry` package to set the page size. As default is uses 12.80 cm x 9.60 cm, but you can change it:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, matrix, chains, scopes, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\makeatletter
\geometry{papersize={32cm,\beamer@paperheight}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{myrect/.style n args = {4}{font=\footnotesize \ttfamily, align=left, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum width=#1cm, minimum height=#2cm, fill=#3, draw=#4}}
    \tikzset{myrect/.default={3}{1}{white}{black}}
    \tikzset{mycon/.style = {rounded corners}}
    \begin{frame}[t,fragile]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix (layer1) [matrix of nodes, nodes={myrect}, column sep=1cm] {
                A&
                |[visible on=<2->]| B&
                |[visible on=<3->]| C&
                |[visible on=<4->]| D\\
            };
            {
                [start chain,every on chain/.style={join}, every join/.style={->}]
                \chainin (layer1-1-1) [];
                \only<5->{\chainin (layer1-1-2) [];}
                \only<6->{\chainin (layer1-1-3) [];}
                \only<7->{\chainin (layer1-1-4) [];}
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```