# Stop motion animation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, automation

I have a series of `eps images` that I would like to display in a sequence of slides in a Beamer presentation. The result would be like a stop motion animation effect. The images are titled `image1.eps` to `image50.eps`. I can obviously do this with a sequence of 50 identical slides, differing only in the index on the image file, but I wanted to see if it's possible to automate the process somehow.

Comment: Welcome! Try `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,50}
{\begin{frame}[t,plain]
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image-\X.eps}
\end{center}
\end{frame}}
\end{document}`.

Comment: I do not mean to advertise for one of my posts, but the answer proposed by Daniel [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435559/141947) helped me a lot. Specifically the second part. It is pretty close to Schrödinger's cat proposal, the only difference being it uses overlays and not new `frame`s.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. Thanks!