# Blend arrow/line from one color to another

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to blend a line from a start color to an end color, such as from red to blue?

Comment: Welcome to the tex.stackexchange.

Comment: See also [tikz pgf - How to shade text in different colors? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192496/how-to-shade-text-in-different-colors) (you can do that with a `\leftrightarrow`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [single arrow,left color=red,right color=blue,
single arrow head extend=3pt,transform shape,minimum height=2cm,anchor=west] 
at (0,0){};

\shade[left color=red,right color=blue] (0,-1) rectangle ++(2,0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

pgfplots has the ability to add these color transitions via `point meta`, see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426912/121799).

[image]