# Change frame subtitle after a framebreak

Tags: beamer, frame-title

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][
  \insertcontinuationcountroman]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Foo}
  \framesubtitle{Bar}
  \lipsum[1]
  \framebreak
  \framesubtitle{Baz}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As it can be seen in the image, the first frame has the proper title, `Foo`, but the wrong subtitle (it should be `Bar` instead of `Baz`). How I can fix this? I know that for the second frame I can just create a new frame like this:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle{Foo II}
  \framesubtitle{Baz}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
```

and avoid my current problem. However I was wondering if it is possible to place an explicit frame break with a new subtitle for the continuation frame without resetting the subtitle for the first frame.

[image]

**Edit** After @Mark showed me this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/beamer-framebreaks-with-different-subtitles) I can do this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
  \only<+>{
    \framesubtitle{Bar}
  }
  \only<+>{
    \framesubtitle{Baz}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to get the correct subtitles in each frame. The problem with this approach, as seen in the image,  is that I want the title on the second frame to be `Foo II` instead of `Foo` (I like the `allowframebreaks` behavior of showing a roman numeral appended to the title of a continuation frame).

[image]

So my question is, can I use the overlay approach to fix the subtitle reset problem but also somehow append roman numerals to the titles of the continuation frames as allow `allowframebreaks` does?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/beamer-framebreaks-with-different-subtitles

Comment: @Mark thanks! I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe some one who understands beamer can help.  I give up.  I would suggest \Roman{beamerpauses}, but that fails.

Comment: Do you really want to encode those slides into just one (logical) frame? I mean, if you are going to type subtitles by hand, why not give each subtitle a frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edited question and [Beamer - How can I add sub-frame numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231783/beamer-how-can-i-add-sub-frame-numbers) you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Foo}
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Bar}
        }
        \only<+>{
            \frametitle{Foo \Roman{slideinframe}}
            \framesubtitle{Baz}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

To make this automatically

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter

\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}

\newcommand*{\augmentframetitle}[1]{%
    \expandafter\frametitle\expandafter
    {\beamer@frametitle #1 \expandafter\ifnum\beamer@slideinframe>1\relax\Roman{slideinframe}\fi}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \augmentframetitle{bar}
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Bar}
        }
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Baz}
        }
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Two questions : i)  can I avoid numbering the firsr frame? (i.e I want the first frame to be `Foo` and the second `Foo II` and ii)  can this be done automatically from the preamble?  I would like to have the `\Roman{slideinframe} ` always appended to the frame title without having to manually place it each time.

Comment: @petobens See the edit

Comment: Awesome! Can you you also please add in the answer the non-automatic solution where the first frame is `Foo` instead of `Foo I`?

Comment: @petobens done!