# Beamer, frame title and subtitle

Tags: beamer

I like to have in frame with option `\allowframebreaks` different `\framesubtitle`. Solution provided by *samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz* in [change-frame-subtitle-after-a-framebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236383/change-frame-subtitle-after-a-framebreak/236654#236654) fulfil this my wish, however I like to change a way of numbering of frames. Instead of `\Roman` numbers i like to have `\arabic` numbered on the following way

```
    (<frame number>/<number of slides in frame>)
```

which in the case when frame has three slides, are numbered as (1/3), (2/3) and (3/3). How to achieve this?

Code in given link is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\newcounter{bar}
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \setcounter{bar}{\insertframeendpage}%
  \addtocounter{bar}{-\insertframestartpage}%
  \addtocounter{bar}{1}%
  (\slideinframe/\thebar)%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{Foo \foo}
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Bar}
        }
\lipsum[1]

%\framebreak
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Baz}
        }
\color{red}\lipsum[2]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

what it do, but consider solution suggested in @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer frame is not divided on slides:

[image]

But when I uncomment lines in above MWE, slides appear, but numbering not works anymore as expected...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the total number of slides within the frame from the start and end pages of the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\newcounter{bar}
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \setcounter{bar}{\insertframeendpage}%
  \addtocounter{bar}{-\insertframestartpage}%
  \addtocounter{bar}{1}%
  (\slideinframe/\thebar)%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Foo \foo}
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Bar}
            \lipsum[1]
        }
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Baz}
            \color{red}\lipsum[2]
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for fast response. It almost work as desired ... with you solution I have problem how to insert text in each slide in frame. If I insert for example `\lipsum[1]` after eacj subtitle ,, text are not in own slide, but it continues and is cut after first frame. Adding `allowsframebreaks` resulted in correct breaking frame into slides, but numbering is corrupted. SO so far only +1 for your effort.

Comment: @Zarko Don't combine this with `allowframebreaks`, this option is not really compatible with overlays. Instead use `\only<...>{...}` etc. to split your text across the slides.

Comment: Hm, this not work as I expected. No separated slides are produced. What then I should do, that thew will do so?

Comment: @Zarko A starting point would be to show your code.

Comment: Now is added MWE by which I tested your solution.

Comment: @Zarko See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see where I should insert my slide contents.  Sorry, that I didn't figured out this myself ...

Comment: @Zarko You're welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately now I discover very unpleasant side effect of your solution: (i) numbers are not incremented for numbered captions, (ii) referencing of images does not work. Please see my new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708259/.